# ¿Cómo permitir el ingreso de paréntesis en un JTextField? - Java

Tags: java, jtextfield

En un formulario tengo un `JTextField` en donde debo controlar que no se ingresen números ni caracteres especiales, pero si debo permitir caracteres como el punto(.) y paréntesis. Tengo el siguiente codigo pero no logro que me permita el ingreso de paréntesis, una ayuda por favor:

```
private void JTXTFSubespecialidadNombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                    
    final char keyChar = evt.getKeyChar();

    if (!(Character.isAlphabetic(keyChar) || (Character.isWhitespace(keyChar)) || keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD || keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS || keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS || keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT || keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
        evt.consume();
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(evt.getKeyChar())) {
        evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(evt.getKeyChar()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que veo mas factible en este caso es utilizar expresiones regulares, donde esta evalua el caracter ingresado y en caso de ser un caracter alfabetico (a-z) (A-Z) o un punto (.) o cualquier parentesis ('(') (')') lo deja ingresar

```
private void JTXTFSubespecialidadNombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                    
    final char keyChar = evt.getKeyChar();
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z\\.()]*)$");
    Matcher mt = pt.matcher(Character.toString(keyChar));

    boolean matchFound = mt.find();
     if(!matchFound) {
       evt.consume();
     } else if (Character.isLowerCase(evt.getKeyChar())) {
        evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(evt.getKeyChar()));
     }
    }
```

Intentelo y me avisa

Comment: Me gusta, es mucho mas sencillo de lo que estaba haciendo, pero hay un problema, no me deja ingresar espacios. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Siento la demora.

Para agregar espacios seria agregar propiamente un espacio al String de la expresion regular

Quedaria asi:
  "^([a-zA-Z\\.() ]*)$"

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma aparte de utilizar expresiones regulares es hacer uso de la tabla ascii, cada tecla en tu teclado tiene un valor numérico en la tabla ascii, por lo que puedes transformar esa tecla a un numero y ahí hacer las respectivas validaciones.

```
   private void JTXTFSubespecialidadNombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 
        char validar = evt.getKeyChar();
        int tecla = (int) evt.getKeyChar(); // Transforma el char a un numero decimal
        
        //espacio en la tabla accii es igual a 32
        //borrar en la tabla accii es igual a 8
        //suprimiir en la tabla accii es igual a 127
        //enter en la tabla accii es igual a 10
        // ( en la tabla ascii es igual a 40
        // ) en la tabla ascii es igual a 41
        // . en la tabla ascii es igual a 46
        
        //Validaciones respectivas
        if (tecla != 32 && tecla != 8 && tecla != 127 && tecla != 10 && tecla != 40 && tecla != 41 && tecla != 46) { 
            //Evita los numeros y caracteres distintos a una letra ya sea mayuscula o minuscula
            if (!Character.isLetter(validar)) {
                evt.consume();                
            }
        }
       
    }
```